# scrolling become slow when having large number of textviews in scrollview

Tags: android, layout, textview, scrollview

I have Scrollview is being filled pragmatically, with large number of textview with background Bitmap loaded from Assets folder. they are being filled as rows. each row has different number of columns, when i have large number of these textviews it scrolling stops to be smooth, i cant use adapter because i have multiple cases and each textview should have a seperate actions, how to make this scrolling more smooth?

I used Overidden text view and overided the :

```
@Override
    public void requestLayout() {
        /*
         * Do nothing here
         */
    }
```

but in the 1st load it still so slow, any ideas?

Comment: An adapter can inflate different layouts for different objects in a list. I would revisit using a ListView with an Adapter.

Comment: did you try with a listview?

Comment: Using a large num of views inside a scrollView can cause slow reaction, because everything the disapears will be created again if it comes back. And then, if You have a image as backgroudn on that view, it´s gonna be more slow. Try to reduce the image to the lowest what You need. How big is that image?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs does ScrollView recycles views when they become not visible?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :). well the images can be reduced, it varies from screen to screen,i am drawing a map for Class Seats or lecture seats, each seat is clickable,i cant imagine Listview would help coz i have to move rows and columns

Answer (score 1):

You can add the android:hardwareAccelerated="false" for a specific activity.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: I dont think I'd be able to use this , this is my manifest info:
android:minSdkVersion="10"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"

when i add this line of code, it gives error. is there anyway to prevent the view from being redrawed again?

Answer (score 0):

I'd still go with the adapter and `ListView` design as you can inflate different layouts for each row just as you're doing already. The only difference is that the `ListView` will handle destroying and creating these views as they are required.
There's no need to make use of the `convertView` in the `getView()` method of the adapter if you will have many different types of view. But it should still scroll much smoother.